# Double quote handling when exporting JSON field with BigQuery

Tags: json, csv, google-bigquery

I am making use of the [JSON datatype](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#json_type) in BigQuery and I have a table that looks like this:

```
myStringField   | myJSONField
----------------|----------------------------------
someStringValue | {"key1":"value1", "key1":"value2"}
```

In SQL, everything works fine. But, when it comes to exporting data, it gets messy. For instance, if I click the "Save results" button and if I choose the "CSV (local file)" option, I obtain the following content in my CSV:

```
myStringField,myJSONField
someStringValue,"{""key1"":""value1"", ""key1"":""value2""}"
```

As you can see, I get "double double quotes" inside my JSON and it makes things complicated to parse for the downstream system that receives the file.

I tried to fix it by using different combinations of [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#JSONPath_format) such as PARSE_JSON(), TO_JSON_STRING(), STRING() but nothing worked and, in some cases, it even made things worse ("triple double quotes").

Ideally, the expected output of my CSV should resemble this:

```
myStringField,myJSONField
someStringValue,{"key1":"value1", "key1":"value2"}
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Same problem here, I found out that exporting to .json is better overall but it didn't fix the problem with JSON fields generated by the query statement

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, exporting JSON fields to a CSV format has some limitations:

- *When you export data in JSON format, INT64 (integer) data types are encoded as JSON strings to preserve 64-bit precision when the data is read by other systems.*
- *When you export a table in JSON format, the symbols <, >, and & are converted by using the unicode notation \uNNNN, where N is a hexadecimal digit. For example, profit&loss becomes profit\u0026loss. This unicode conversion is done to avoid security vulnerabilities.*

Check out the export limitations here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations

Regarding the export format you mentioned, that is the expected way to escape the double quote characters in CSV. So this is the expected output.

First quotes are there because of the CSV encode mechanism for strings and every other double quote inside that string will be escaped with another double quote.

```
"{""key1"":""value1""}"
```

If you are parsing this csv with any parser out there, this format should be supported with the right setup.